# INSERT into MYSQL and then before closing the connection select the insert id and then adding this id to 3 other tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I am pretty new to the world of SQL so sorry for my ignorance on this.

I have a form on an admin page that adds a player to a team database. When the form is submitted what I need to have happen is:

- The player gets inserted into players table (player_id is Primary key and used in next step).
- A select statement runs to get the player_id.
- Then inserts that into 2 other tables:

  - team_players and cards.

Below is the best representation of what I have tried:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con2, $_POST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con2, $_POST['last_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con2, $_POST['email']);
$validation_code = md5($email + microtime());


$sql0 ="INSERT INTO players 
(first_name, last_name, email, validation_code)                        
VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name','$email', '$validation_code')";



$sql01 = "SELECT player_id FROM players WHERE email='$email'";
$result01 = $con2->query($sql01);

if ($result01->num_rows > 0) {
$row01 = $result01->fetch_assoc();

$playerID = $row01['player_id'];
echo $playerID; //In for debugging. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't


$sql02 = "INSERT INTO team_players, cards (player_id, team_id)
VALUES('$playerID', '$id')";
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: don't do `select player_id`. you should be using `last_insert_id()` to securely get the ID of your new record. And exactly HOW is this code not working?

Comment: @tadman thank you for the response. I will be sure to update my code.

Comment: @MarcB it inserts the player but nothing else gets inserted to any of the other tables. With last_inster_id()  what if another admin is adding a player at the same time? Is there a potential for crossing the insterted ID or is this specific to this query?

Comment: well, you don't have any other inserts in the above code. you have one insert and one select, then define the sql for another insert, but never execute it. and that final insert definition is bad anyways. you can't insert into more than one table at a time anyways.

Comment: @MarcB  when you say I am not executing the last INSERT how am I not executing it? Does it need to be positioned differently? I did try the last insert in 2 separate INSERTS but that yielded the same result of nothing being added except the the player table.

Comment: you have no `->query()` call for it. `$sql = 'blah blah blah'` is just defining a string. until you actually sent that string to the db via `->query($sql)`, it STAYS a php string, and the fact that it looks like sql is irrelevant. php has no idea what sql is. it's text like any other as far as php is concerned.

Comment: @MarcB thank you. I feel like an idiot. I appreciate the help on that aspect.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID (or its PHP counterpart) is session specific. So there's no danger. Use that instead. This is thoroughly covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot insert into two tables using one query.

You can use a **transaction** and have both of them be contained within one transaction.

Otherwise execute  two separate queries for each insertion.
One more thing, you have not executed the query for inserting to first table

```
  START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO team_players (player_id, team_id) VALUES (...);
INSERT INTO cards (player_id, team_id) VALUES  (...);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. So I updated the query with 2 separate queries and fixed the execution on the first query. It works now but the user gets added to the database twice now. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you executing query twice?

Comment: Not intentionally. I think the problem is is that I am posting to the same page because the form is in a modal and so when I hit submit, the page processes the form again after it reloads.

Comment: Okay then. lets try giving another file in action attribute with these actions